# Define object & pass it to a partial

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

What I want to do:

```
{{>myPartial foo={bar:1} }}
```

I want to define an object while passing it to a partial. Is that possible?

---

I know it's possible to pass an existing object like

```
{{>myPartial foo=foo}}
```

But I want to define my object within my markup.

Why? Well basically because it's just to define layout. I want to avoid to determine layout decisions on the backend.
My partial is a table layout, and I want to hide specific columns.

But instead of using multiple properties like

```
{{>myPartial hideFoo=true hideBar=true}}
```

I want to use a single object `hide`

```
{{>myPartial hide={foo:true,bar:true} }}
```

Comment: did my answer worked for you?

Comment: If you post a question, please give feedback if someone answers, so upcoming users will know if an answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a new context to a partial:

```
{{> myPartial context }}
```

**Example:**

```
var data = {
  title: "Foo Bar",
    foo: ["foo1", "foo2"],
    bar: ["bar1", "bar2"],
    hide: {
        foo: true,
        bar: false
    }
};

var content = "{{title}} {{> myPartial hide }}";
var partialContent = "<div class=\"{{#if foo}}hideFoo{{/if}} {{#if bar}}hideBar{{/if}}\">Hide</div>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(content);
Handlebars.registerPartial("foo", partialContent);
template(data);
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="hideFoo hideBar">Hide</div>
```

Another way is to pass a JSON string, instead of an object, using a helper in the way:

```
//helper
Handlebars.registerHelper("parseJSON", function(string, options) {
  return options.fn(JSON.parse(string));
});

//template    
{{#parseJSON '{"foo": true,"bar": true}'}}
     {{> myPartial}}
{{/parseJSON}}
```

**Demo:**

```js
//Compile main template
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#template").html());

//Register partial
Handlebars.registerPartial("myPartial", $("#myPartial").html());

//Register parseJSON helper
Handlebars.registerHelper("parseJSON", function(string, options) {
  return options.fn(JSON.parse(string));
});

//Your data
var data = {
  title: "Foo Bar"
};


document.body.innerHTML = template(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<!-- template.html -->
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  
  <h3>First Partial:</h3>
  {{#parseJSON '{"foo": true,"bar": false}'}}
      {{> myPartial}}
  {{/parseJSON}}
  
  <h3>Second Partial:</h3> 
  {{#parseJSON '{"foo": false,"bar": false}'}}
      {{> myPartial}}
  {{/parseJSON}}
</script>

<script id="myPartial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div>hide.foo: {{foo}}</div>
  <div>hide.bar: {{bar}}</div>
</script>
```